# How can my Perl program tell if is running under mod_perl?

Tags: perl, mod-perl2

How can my Perl program tell if is running under mod_perl?

I'm thinking along the lines of global variables or environment variables.

I am only bothered about mod_perl >= 2.

Comment: [The manual](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/coding/coding.html) says it's `$ENV{MOD_PERL}`.

Comment: P.S. You could have googled your question's title "as is".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/coding/coding.html#Environment_Variables says that there will be an environment variable `MOD_PERL`, so you could test for that using the expression

```
exists $ENV{MOD_PERL}
```

Answer (score 8):

According to ["Environment Variables" in the mod_perl user's guide](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/coding/coding.html#Environment_Variables):

> `$ENV{MOD_PERL}` - is set to the mod_perl version the server is running under. e.g.:
>
> ```
>   mod_perl/2.000002
> ```
>
> If `$ENV{MOD_PERL}` doesn't exist, most likely you are not running under mod_perl.
>
> ```
>   die "I refuse to work without mod_perl!" unless exists $ENV{MOD_PERL};
> ```

(see the above link for more information).